# Evans chapter 5, example 1

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image: ex1-ch5]
In this example we want to show $v$ is weak derivative of $u$. In last line we apply integration by parts. My question is why $\phi(2)$ vanishes. $2 \notin U$, how can we talk about $\phi(2)$?. Is it vanishes due to compact support? Or should we think the $0$-extension of $\phi$ i.e, $\bar{\phi}(x)=\phi(x)$ if $x \in U$ and $\bar{\phi}(x)=0$ if $x \notin U$.

Comment: You are correct that it follows from compact support: if its support is compact in $(0,2)$, then it can naturally be extended by 0 to $\{0, 2\}$.

Comment: thanks for answer!